# Trying to get through public folder in Laravel

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel

I have setup Apache to serve myapp directory as the root one.

My folder structure (a bit simplified) is:

```
myapp/
├── backend
│   ├── app
│   ├── artisan
│   ├── bootstrap
│   ├── composer.json
│   ├── composer.lock
│   ├── config
│   ├── database
│   ├── doc
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── public
│   ├── resources
│   ├── server.php
│   ├── storage
│   ├── tests
│   └── vendor
├── frontend
└── .htaccess
```

myapp/.htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ backend/public/$1
```

However, when I try to load localhost/api/someController, I get Not Found Http Exception - 404. When I place the root in /var/www/html/ try to load localhost/myapp/backend/public/someController, it does work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try routing it to `index.php`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ backend/public/index.php/$1
```

Comment: Tried the [L] flag? The `.htaccess` file in Laravel docs seems to have it

Comment: Also, you need to have AcceptPathInfo enabled in your server. See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo